# Storing array of random dates over a possibly large range in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

So my app takes in a task from the client and the client specific on a calendar which days he will be working on that task, the range would be over a span of years and on random days. And I want to store the dates and task description on database

For example: ['01-02-1992', '01-09-1992', '09-09-2016']. The array could be really long too.

So what is the most efficient way to store this in database? I read on stackoverflow that storing array is bad. What if I just store everything in a string, so in the above example it would be 010219920109199209092016, then I will just "decode" it after I extract it from database. Any good advise or ideas?

Comment: I would go with adding a new table (task_id, date) and add all the dates as datatime value.

Comment: Do you mind explaining it a bit so I can get a better understanding? like what are the advantage of doing it like that over storing it in other method. Thanks!!

Comment: 1. It is a cleaner and more convenient way to store dates in a date format. 2. When you select the values later, you won't have to decode it each time. So the cost of decoding a string will be removed. 3. Instead of fetching a long string from the database you can easily find if a specific date (or range) exists using simple queries.